# how to play video from url

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am beginner in android development and try to play video from link. But it's giving error `"sorry,we can't play this video"`. I tried so many links but for all links its show same error.

My code is the following

```
public class VideoDemo extends Activity {

        private static final String path ="http://demo.digi-corp.com/S2LWebservice/Resources/SampleVideo.mp4";
 private VideoView video;
 private MediaController ctlr;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

            video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
            video.setVideoPath(path);

            ctlr = new MediaController(this);
            ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setMediaController(ctlr);
            video.requestFocus();
     }
}
```

---

Logcat shows following error message:

```
04-12 15:04:54.245: ERROR/PlayerDriver(554): HandleErrorEvent: PVMFErrTimeout
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the format to me. It might help to see the actual console error message with callstack, could you paste the full logcat output?

Comment: try using setVideoPath instead

Answer (score 47):

It has something to do with your link and content. Try the following two links:

```
    String path="http://www.ted.com/talks/download/video/8584/talk/761";
    String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";

    Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);

    VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
```

Start with "path1", it is a small light weight video stream and then try the "path", it is a higher resolution than "path1", a perfect high resolution for the mobile phone.

Comment: well, web master at www.ted.com will be pissed at my answer for using their url which all the all the android devs here testing it against! Please find your own video url :)

Comment: i do the same but still i cant play .mp4 video 08-12 14:37:30.599: D/MediaPlayer(23633): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side 08-12 14:37:33.095: E/MediaPlayer(23633): error (1, -2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: E/MediaPlayer(23633): Error (1,-2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: D/VideoView(23633): Error: 1,-2147483648 got this error

Comment: To everyone who is getting a 404 error - It is because That TED Talk no longer exists. Find a new video URL to try instead.

Comment: Couldn't open http://xxxx.com/...
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://xxxx.com/test.mp4

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);      

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            finish();               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `FullscreenVideoView` class. Its a small library project. It's video progress dialog is build in. it's gradle is :

```
compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.0'
```

your VideoView xml is like this

> ```
> <com.github.rtoshiro.view.video.FullscreenVideoLayout
>         android:id="@+id/videoview"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
> ```

In your activity , initialize it using this way:

> ```
>     FullscreenVideoLayout videoLayout;
>
> videoLayout = (FullscreenVideoLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
>         videoLayout.setActivity(this);
>
>         Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("YOUR_VIDEO_URL");
>         try {
>             videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);
>
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

If want to know more then visit [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1906), where the code snippets above also come from. Credits to [Toshiro](https://android-arsenal.com/user/rtoshiro)

**Edit:**
gradle path has been updated. compile it now

```
compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.2'
```

Comment: @Sajedul library is good but after play for some seconds it will stop playing. MediaPlayer: error(1, -1004) will print in logcat. why is it so?I am trying to play http://sharemyideo.esy.es/upload/videos/922a4a6a4e370acb94c84fe0039c66f2.mp4 this video.

Comment: they added new release in their stable channel. Can you update it's gradle path
compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.2'
Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: will this support both **Youtube** and **Vimeo** URLs?

Answer (score 4):

Try Exoplayer2

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

It is highly customisable

```
    private void initializePlayer() {
         player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
             new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
             new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

         playerView.setPlayer(player);

         player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
         player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url_mp3));
     MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
     player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
    }

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
  return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
      new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
      createMediaSource(uri);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
   initializePlayer();
 }
}
```

Check this url for more details

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#2

Answer (score 1):

please check this link :
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

**videoview** can't support some **codec** .

**i suggested you to use mediaplayer , when get "sorry , can't play video"**

Answer (score 1):

I also got stuck with this issue. 
I got correct response from server, but couldn`t play video. After long time I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120750/7856586).
Maybe, in future this link will be invalid. 
So, here is my correct code

```
    Uri video = Uri.parse("Your link should be in this place "); 
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(video); 

   mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true); //Very important line, add it to Your code
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  // here write another part of code, which provides starting the video
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [UniversalVideoView](https://github.com/linsea/UniversalVideoView) library its simple and straight forward with controller as well.

Here is the code to play the video
Add this dependancyy in build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.linsea:universalvideoview:1.1.0@aar'
```

Java Code

```
        UniversalVideoView mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/contactform-d9534.appspot.com/o/Vexento%20-%20Masked%20Heroes.mp4?alt=media&token=74c2e448-5b1b-47b7-b761-66409bcfbf56");
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        UniversalMediaController mMediaController = findViewById(R.id.media_controller);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        mVideoView.start();
```

Xml Code

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <com.universalvideoview.UniversalVideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:uvv_autoRotation="true"
                app:uvv_fitXY="false" />

            <com.universalvideoview.UniversalMediaController
                android:id="@+id/media_controller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                app:uvv_scalable="true" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether your phone supports the video format or not.Even I had the problem when playing a 3gp file but it played a mp4 file perfectly.