# Playing video from URL -Android

Tags: android

In the following code what ami doing wrong the video dosnt seem to play here.Is that the permission issue if so what should be included in the manifest file
this 
***main.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="true">
         <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"></LinearLayout>
         <MediaController android:id="@+id/mediacnt" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></MediaController>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
         <Gallery android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Gallery>
         <VideoView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/vv" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></VideoView>

     </LinearLayout>
```

this is ***java class***

```
 package com.gallery;
     import java.net.URL;

     import android.app.Activity;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.MediaController;
     import android.widget.Toast;
     import android.widget.VideoView;

     public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {
         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
     // Set video link (mp4 format )
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEbxLDuecHU&playnext=1&list=PL040F3034C69B1674");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();


         }
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url

Comment: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidVideoComponent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

add the Internet permission to applications' manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this link you should see [AndroidVideoComponent](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidVideoComponent.aspx) this also [MediaPlayerDemo_Video](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html)

Comment: I do it and works when I´m connected via 3G but when I connect via WIFI it doesn´t work, any clue?? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If you want to play a video from a URL in the wifi state, you need to add the wifi and network state permissions in the manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```