# Error while playing the mp4 videos from server in Android

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview

1.I used the following code to play videos from server.
2.But it displays the error sorry , video can not be played .

```
url=bundle.getString("url");
myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);   
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
{
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    myVideoView.start();
            }
 });
```

Please help me how to stream mp4 videos in android.

Comment: which error you get.. logcat error post ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
String path="http://www.ted.com/talks/download/video/8584/talk/761";
String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";

Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);

VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Start with "path1", it is a small light weight video stream and then try the "path", it is a higher resolution than "path1", a perfect high resolution for the mobile phone.
got answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659346/1218762

Comment: 3gp videos working fine.I have problem in  playing mp4 videos from server.

Comment: buddy just try hear .mp4 link

Comment: go to this link buddy try this link http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-live-streaming-using-video-view.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.documentariesandyou));
 mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

> put your .mp4 video into raw folder

Comment: It works fine but  i want to play videos directly from server.when the video size is large.it not buffers the videos completely and the error message is displayed.